# Oracle group by work time period and non work time period

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I cannot find solution how to use Select statement in Oracle with  group by.

I need to group by timestamp column with work time period (from 09:00 to 21:00 of "current day") and second period from (21:01 previous day to 08:59 of "current day")
within one mounth.

any advice is welcome.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The key to this grouping is to subtract 9 hours from the datetime to get the "workdate" and then use the `hour` function to determine whether it is a work hour or something else.  Here is an example:

```
select trunc(worktime - 9.0/24) as workdate,
       (case when hour(worktime) between 8 and 20 then 'WorkHours' else 'OtherHours' end),
       count(*)
from t
group by trunc(worktime - 9.0/24),
         (case when hour(worktime) between 8 and 20 then 'WorkHours' else 'OtherHours' end);
```

To check for a particular month, you probably want to use the `workdate` rather than the actual date (so the first nine hours of the month are really part of the previous month).

Answer (score 0):

```
group by 
       trunc(timestamp_col, 'MM')
     , case 
          when to_char(timestamp_col, 'hh24') between '08' and '20' 
          then 'work' 
          else 'other'
       end
```

`trunc(timestamp_col, 'MM')`  -- give you the month

```
case 
          when to_char(timestamp_col, 'hh24') between '08' and '20' 
          then 'work' 
          else 'other'
       end
```

-- give you either 'work' or 'other'